# Replace this "&nbsp;" with this " " using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an issue with this blank space " " showing up in my textbox if the table row is null.  so i would like to replace this "`&nbsp;`" with this "". For example here is what i have:

```
StartTime.Text = row.Cells[5].Text;
```

so here is pseudo-code of what i am trying to achieve:

```
if (StartTime.Text == ""&nbsp;" then replace it with "  ")
else show the value of StartTime.Text
```

I know my C# skills is so bad so please help.  thanks

Comment: change condition to  `StartTime.Text == @""&nbsp;"`

Comment: Fix it on the render, how you render that cell ?

Comment: `HtmlDecode` is your friend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what about `StartTime.Text = row.Cells[5].Text.Replace("&nbsp", " ")`

or i haven't understood the question correctly

Comment: thanks man, u saved my day.  that was easy and simple solution. thanks again

Comment: one more question, how do i replace if i have more than one thing to replace with " ".  For example, i want to replace "&nbsp" and "nbsp" with this " ". thnx

Comment: Text.Replace("&nbsp", " ").Replace("nbsp", " ")...
.... and so on. There might be a more elegant way, but this is what i tend to use.